# How can I POST from a form to my node.js application in a Docker Desktop Kubernetes cluster

Tags: html, node.js, docker, kubernetes, post

I have a yaml file for Kubernetes that looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-node-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-node-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-node-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-node-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-node-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: node-app
          image: <my image>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

Here's the line for the POST request from an HTML page:

```
<form action="http://my-node-app-service:3000/" method="post">
```

It doesn't work and gives me a Server Not Found error in my browser.

I expected the POST request to go through successfully and write to my database, but it looks like where I'm posting to is wrong. Where should I post to?

Comment: have you set up an ingress object `kubectl get ingress`? is your container exposing port 3000?

Comment: I do not have an ingress object! I'm not sure how that works. I'll look into it. I believe my container is exposing port 3000 because i can go to localhost:3000 and see the node application.

Comment: Is an ingress rule something like this??

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-node-app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-node-app-service
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-node-app-service
            port:
              number: 3000

Comment: although you have named the service `my-node-app-service` it is still serving at `localhost:3000`. [you can learn more about ingress object here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Comment: I know in Docker I was able to do a post request like this but looks like it's not as simple in Kubernetes? my-node-app-service doesn't map to localhost?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123401/how-to-access-hosts-localhost-from-inside-kubernetes-cluster

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if any of below answer resolves you issues or do share your solution if manage to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

If your **HTML** is running in the same **Kubernetes** cluster then ideally it should be working, both **service**, **deployment** & **HTML** should be in same namespace of k8s too.

If your **HTML** hosted outside of the **k8s cluster** it won't work that, **service-name** that you have used is correct way but only resolves **internally**.

**Run command**

```
kubectl get svc
```

as your service is type:**LoadBalancer** you will see the **ExternalIP**

Use that IP to hit the service. IP mostly available if you are running K8s on cloud provider GCP, AWS etc.

```
<form action="http://IPX.XX.X.X:3000/" method="post">
```

You can also Map this **IP** to your Domain if you want, Alternative way is to use **ingress** to **expose** your service and use that Domain in HTML.

```
<form action="http://example.com:3000/" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Docker Desktop for deploying your application to Kubernetes. You can try changing your `Service` to a `type: NodePort` instead of a `type: LoadBalancer`

It should look something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-node-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-node-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      nodePort: 30000 # Will be accessible on localhost:30000
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort
```

After adjusting the service you will able to reach your application on http://localhost:30000

Additionally since your application is now listening on http://localhost:30000

You can set the form of your application to send a POST request to your node.js application by adjusting it in the following way.

```
<form action="http://localhost:30000/" method="post">
```

And this should resolve your case for sending a post request to your application and writing the form data into the database.

p.s. If you're interested in the difference between a `LoadBalancer` and a `NodePort` I recommend this [thread here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443138/difference-between-nodeport-and-loadbalancer)